# setting java arguments in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, arguments

I want to run my java code with below arguments in eclipse.

```
java -cp "../../" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=peer01KeyStore.jks  MainCmd -v -p 0 -c config.peer01.properties
```

So, I clicked "run->run configuration->Java Application->Arguments" and I inputed the long arguments without the first "java" (-cp "../../" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=peer01KeyStore.jks  MainCmd -v -p 0 -c config.peer01.properties) in "Program arguments". But it doesn't work.

The arguments meaning is as follows and I'm not sure them exactly.

- -cp "../../"  : class path
- -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=peer01KeyStore.jks : arguments for OpenSSL
- MainCmd -v -p 0 -c : main class(MainCmd) with options
- config.peer01.properties : configuration file (input file)

I hope how to set the arguments in detail. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: As you can see there are two boxes: _Program_ arguments and _VM_ arguments. `-cp` would be VM argument (but better use the _Classpath_ tab), the trust store as well. The rest would be progam arguments but should probably be passed in individual lines. Refer to the eclipse help for details. `MainCmd` on the other hand is _not_ an argument and would be set in the _Main_ tab.

Comment: hahaha this user is not accepting any answer how rude :)) I will upvote your answers...

Comment: @sgpalit In my local time, now is dinner time and so I had it. I'm just a little late but not rude.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Oh, I saw your comments therefore I thought that you would not accept any answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, Split your arguments as program arguments and VM arguments.

For example; (I think)

Program Argument:

> -v -p 0 -c config.peer01.properties

VM argument;

> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=peer01KeyStore.jks

Run configuration
[image: Run configuration]

Project Properties for classpath, Add libraries or projects to classpath from project properties
[image: Project Properties for classpath]

Comment: There is a separate tab in the Run Configuration for the Classpath.

Comment: @Yusuf KARTAL Thanks for your detail picture comment

Answer (score 6):

you can get argument from command line into eclipse into following manner,
please refer below picture,

[image]

> And for class path there is another separate tab provided by eclipse
>   into same window where we are entering argument,  beside argument tab
>   one more tab is "classpath"

Comment: Beautiful illustration, how did you create this picture video.

Comment: @Anil the "picture video" is an animated [gif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF) :)

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming MainCmd is your Main class. There are basically two types of arguments.

Program arguments are arguments passed to your program and available in the args array of your main method

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

These are to be set in Program Arguments box above.
For you those will be

```
-v -p 0 -c config.peer01.properties
```

And then there are VM arguments. VM arguments are passed to the virtual machine and are designed to instruct the VM to do something.

These are to be set in VM arguments box above.
For you those will be

```
-cp "../../" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=peer01KeyStore.jks
```